# Why is this MYSQL query using subqueries so slow?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm building an API that responds the query below, but it takes 7.5 seconds on average to execute. Could someone help me make it quicker?

```sql
SELECT 
    peers.ip, 
    peers.datetime AS first_seen, 
    (SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM uptimes WHERE ip = peers.ip) AS last_seen,
    peers.user_agent, 
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM uptimes WHERE ip = peers.ip) AS total_uptime,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tries WHERE datetime >= peers.datetime) AS tries,
    ((SELECT total_uptime) / (SELECT tries)) AS average_uptime
    FROM peers, uptimes
    WHERE peers.ip=uptimes.ip
    GROUP BY peers.ip
    HAVING total_uptime > 10
    ORDER BY average_uptime DESC
    LIMIT 100;
```

The API response looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "ip": "200.0.0.24",
    "first_seen": "1584106440008",
    "last_seen": "1584116482293",
    "user_agent": "Grin++ 0.7.5",
    "total_uptime": 40,
    "tries": 40,
    "average_uptime": 1
  },
  ...
]
```

And below are the tables used in the query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `peers` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_agent` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ip_UNIQUE` (`ip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=772 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `uptimes` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_agent` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3567 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `tries` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3567 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed. (Not performance related, though.)

Answer (score 1):

1. For table `uptimes`, is your unique key meant to be on column `ip` rather than `id`? Having indexes on the filter attribute `ip` could significantly increase the speed of second subquery. Also, specifying unique constraints/indices on the primary key is redundant.
2. The 3rd and 4th subqueries are going to be expensive, as you are accessing the entire `tries` table for every peer. A B-tree index on `tries.datetime` might help a little, but likely not much.
3. Not performance related, but what strikes me as odd is that `tries` are not organized by `ip`. Just thought I'd mention it on the off chance it's actually an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons for slow, A) every table has PRIMARY KEY and next line is a redundant key that should be removed. B) If your datetime datatype was changed from VARCHAR to DATETIME, the column would be smaller for storage, faster to manage and more useful, display Date and Time and you could SELECT datetime BETWEEN startdate AND enddate. C) It is likely the use of CHARSET utf8mb4 contributes to time required for processing. If this is a REQUIREMENT, not much you can do about this detail other than tuning your MySQL configuration. View my profile, Network profile for free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.